# Non-const constexpr member function does not compile with Intel compiler

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, icc

Consider the following example:

```
#include <array>

class int_wrapper {
    public:
        constexpr int_wrapper()
            : i(0)
        {}

        constexpr auto
        value() -> int& {
            return i;
        }
        constexpr auto
        value() const -> const int& {
            return i;
        }

    private:
        int i;
};

constexpr auto
f() -> int_wrapper {
    int_wrapper w;
    w.value() = 10;
    return w;
}

auto g() {
    constexpr auto w = f();

    std::array<double,w.value()> a;
}
```

Non-const constexpr member functions seems to be a c++14 feature.
It compiles with gcc and clang with -std=c++17.

With icpc 17.0.4, it does not compile on my machine:

```
test.cpp(14): error: cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone
          value() const -> const int& {
          ^

test.cpp(11): error: qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type "int &" to initializer of type "const int"
              return i;
                     ^
```

It seems to by consistent with [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) at entry "fixing constexpr member functions without const".
However it compiles just fine with icpc 17 [here](https://godbolt.org/g/vaKXar)! So my question is why does it compiles just fine with icpc on godbolt but not on my machine? Is there feature differences between minor releases of icpc ? Or is there some installation-dependent stuff that I am not aware of ?

Comment: Can you try removing `const` from `const int&`?

Comment: @Yashas There are two non ambiguous overloads based on the fact that one method is const and the other is not. It always worked without constexpr. With constexpr, constexpr implied const in C++11 which made the code ambiguous. But with C++14 constexpr does not imply const anymore

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not notice that one was a `const` member function.

Comment: See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3669.pdf

Comment: Sorry, I see that you already wrote what I was asking about in your question...

Comment: BTW `-std=c++14` or `-std=gnu++14` gives the same error as `-std=c++17`

Comment: On both your machine and GodBolt?

Comment: @underscore_d Sorry I wasn't clear. With intel 17 on godbolt, it works with no flags, `c++14`, `gnu++14` and `c++17`.  With intel 17 on my machine it doesnt work with no flags ("cant compile without c++11 flag"), nor `c++14`, `gnu++14` nor `c++17` (same error message for those 3 flags, `cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone`)

Comment: And the error message with `c++11` is quite interesting : `warning #3699: constexpr non-static member function will not be implicitly 'const' in `C++14`` and then again `cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone`. This is the correct behavior of `c++11` but the funny thing is that it mentions explicitly that it will work  in `c++14`...